# How do you include 'com.google.protobuf' on android project (gradle) as full but not as lite?

Tags: android, android-ndk, build.gradle, protocol-buffers, gradle-plugin

I am trying to use a protobuf generated code to decode messages coming from the network. I have a .proto file which looks like this :

```
syntax = "proto3";

message CanData {
  string id = 1; // name
  Data data1 = 2;
  Data data2 = 3;     
}
message Data {
    oneof data1 {
        int32 int_type = 2; // Magic and other int types
        float float_type = 3; // Timestamp and other float types
        uint32 unsigned_type = 4; // unsigned types
    }
}
```

When I generate the code using the protoc command. It works succesfully. But then I open the android project and it does not work as expected. I get errors looking as on the following line:

```
Error:(11, 26) error: cannot find symbol class ExtensionRegistry
Error:(1719, 43) error: package com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3 does not exist
Error:(1716, 55) error: package com.google.protobuf.Descriptors does not exist
Error:(1724, 43) error: package com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3 does not exist
Error:(1721, 55) error: package com.google.protobuf.Descriptors does not exist
```

There is many more errors. But for simplicity and clarity I kept them away.

Then looking on the internet, we came accross a bunch of solutions that do not work for us as for exemple what we tried to do in the build.gradle :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And build.gradle(Module app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "oronos.oronosmobileapp"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

I think that the lite version:

> com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.0

is not the one I am looking for, But I am unable to find the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one here

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java
compile group: 'com.google.protobuf', name: 'protobuf-java', version: '3.5.1'
```

or

```
compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.5.1'
```

You can simply google it https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java

Comment: later compile changed to implementation but it still worked to solve the build error:
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.5.1'